# The best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to loop my background music in my game however am receiving the error above when putting this if statement in the update function:

```
if (!songStart)
{
    MediaPlayer.Play(backgroundMusic); // error occuring here
    songStart = true;
}
```

when I put this into load content the error dissapears however  I need it in the update so that it is constantly checking if the song is not playing `(!songstart)`.

I currently have this in load content to load the song:

```
Song backgroundMusic = Content.Load<Song>("backgroundMusic");
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
```

EDIT: Just noticed I am also having the follows error, may this have something to do with it?

'Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.SongCollection'

Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error, and what is the full error text? I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code to show where the error is occuring. The full error is as follows. 'Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.Play(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song)' has some invalid arguments \C:\GPT2\BouncingBallXNA\BouncingBallXNA\BouncingBallXNA\MainGame.cs 108 17 BouncingBallXNA'

Comment: `MediaPlayer.Play` wants a `Song`, and you are passing it a `SoundEffect`. See my answer.

Comment: Also, if you get a chance take a look at this tutorial:  http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/using-xact  You can use XACT to achieve a bit more control over your audio in XNA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that bool to check if the audio is already playing, you can use:

```
if(MediaPlayer.State != MediaState.Playing)
```

And for your error, you probably have two variables named `backgroundMusic`, I think that your class variable is a `SoundEffect` (as I read in your previous question), and you have a `Song` variable with the same name declared in your `LoadContent`. You should remove the first one.

Comment: Thanks for that, it saved me some code! :) - Any idea why the errors still occuring?

Comment: I think that you have two variables named `backgroundMusic`, that's why if you use that piece of code in your `LoadContent` the error disappears.

Comment: I can confirm the only variable for backgroundMusic I have is as follows in the load content:

           Song backgroundMusic = Content.Load<Song>("backgroundMusic");

Comment: You can't declare that in the LoadContent if you need it in the Update method, move it as a class variable.

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel stupid!! Thanks, the error has now disappeared, currently running the game and waiting for the music to get to the end to see if it loops as it should. Fingers crossed!!